# How can I build a category system with Ember?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I would like to build a category system with endless subcategories in Ember and Ember Data. It should have the following URL:

`URL/category/{Category}/{SubCategory}/{SubSubCategory}/...`

Is there any way I can achieve this without using query parameters?

Comment: you have a few different routes there. `this.route('category', {path: 'category/:category'});` will only get you as far as `URL/category/{Category}` so you'll need to embed a few more routes - `this.resource('categorys', {path: 'category'}, function(){ this.resource('category', {path: '/:category;}, function(){ this.resource('subcategory', {path: '/subgategory'}, function(){}`  etc

Comment: Id read up on nested resources in the ember docs http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_nested-resources

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, but I I think you misunderstood my question. I can not use nested routes, because I want endless subcategories. I modified my question and I hope it is now easier to understand.

Comment: I don't think your question is specific enough. What other constrains you have? What have you tried and why it didn't work?

Comment: The answer is no, the router doesn't support this, you must define routes in order to use them.  You'll have to use query params, and then use some sort of hack at that if you don't plan on defining a million sub[n]categories